# What's wrong with gdb and stdout?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

Please look this simple gdb session.

I can call printf after a break, but I just can't call anything that contains stdout. What am I doing wrong?

```
(gdb) call printf("Hi :)\n")
Hi :)
$1 = 6
(gdb) call fprintf(stdout, "Bug!\n")

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7491d1d in vfprintf () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
The program being debugged was signaled while in a function called from GDB.
GDB remains in the frame where the signal was received.
To change this behavior use "set unwindonsignal on".
Evaluation of the expression containing the function
(fprintf) will be abandoned.
When the function is done executing, GDB will silently stop.
(gdb)
```

My breakpoint is on the 3rd line of this very tiny program:

```
int main() {
    int x[20] = {};
    x[0] = 3;
}
```

Which was compiled using these flags:

```
CFLAGS =-g -Wall -O0 -std=c11
LDLIBS=
```

I'm using gdb:

```
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3) 7.7
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine here for a tiny test program. What context are you calling `fprintf()` in? What does `(gdb) p stdout` say? What's the GDB version?

Comment: It's a very tiny program, called do-nothing. It just set values to variables. stdout is -136494080 to gdb. I'm using gdb GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.7-0ubuntu3) 7.7 (This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu"). Thanks

Comment: Works fine here with `GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.8-1ubuntu4) 7.8.0.20141001-cvs` (Ubuntu 14.10, x86_64) using the same test program and flags.

Comment: I can't find a `printf` or `fprintf` in your tiny program. Are you certain what program you're d'bugging?

Comment: Works fine here. But my "p stdout" produces this:
$4 = (_IO_FILE *) 0x7ffff7dd4400 <_IO_2_1_stdout_>.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you don't have debuginfo installed for libc, and no other debuginfo for `stdout` has been generated, either.

However, `stdout` is still visible as an ELF symbol.  gdb, in a decision that probably made sense in the early 90s, assumes that the type of such a symbol is `int`.  But, this has a different size than a pointer ... leading to a crash.

I think you can work around this by casting it to the right type, using the `{}` extension.  Or, simplest, install the glibc debuginfo.  Many distros have an easy way to do this.